# Node.js: How can i store the jsonObj in a global variable after converting CSV to JSON by using csvtojson

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, csv

I want to store the jsonObj in a global variable. However, it doesn't work.

```
var jsonContent;

csvConverter.on("end_parsed", function(jsonObj){
//   console.log(jsonObj);
       jsonContent = jsonObj;
});

console.log(jsonContent);
```

jsonObj can be printed correctly inside {...}. But why can't I pass it to a global variable? The result of "console.log(jsonContent);" is still undefined.

```
undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jsonContent` *is* global in the sense that it is available everywhere in your JS file. The problem is that `csvConverter.on` is **asynchronous**, so it will not block the program while it runs. Therefore, you will not be able to use `jsonContent` until after `csvConverter.on` runs its callback.

If you need to use `jsonObj`, you have to use it *after* your callback to `csvConcerter` runs. In order to do so, you can simply wrap your logic in a function and run that function once your callback is called:

```
var jsonContent;

csvConverter.on("end_parsed", function(jsonObj){
  jsonContent = jsonObj;
  runLogic();
});

function runLogic() {
  // this function will run after csvConverter.on callback is called
  console.log(jsonContent);
}
```